# Problem when mounting file system of local-machine in database Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, mounted-volumes

I am trying to mount a local file system in a Docker container for a database.

As written in the instructions in the official repository https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb:

> Using a custom MariaDB configuration file
> The startup configuration is specified in the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf, and that file in turn includes any files found in the /etc/mysql/conf.d directory that end with .cnf. Settings in files in this directory will augment and/or override settings in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. If you want to use a customized MariaDB configuration, you can create your alternative configuration file in a directory on the host machine and then mount that directory location as /etc/mysql/conf.d inside the mariadb container.
>
> If /my/custom/config-file.cnf is the path and name of your custom
> configuration file, you can start your mariadb container like this
> (note that only the directory path of the custom config file is used
> in this command):

```
$ docker run --name some-mariadb -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:tag
```

Referring to this instruction, at the root of my project, I created the **databases** directory, and I wrote the following in the docker-compose file:

```
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 111111
    volumes:
     - ./databases:/var/lib/mysql
```

After that, I run the command:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get the following message:

> Creating docker-proj_adminer_1 ... done Creating docker-proj_db_1
> ... done Attaching to docker-proj_db_1, docker-proj_adminer_1 db_1
> | 2021-06-27 17:15:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for
> MariaDB Server 1:10.5.11+maria~focal started. db_1       | 2021-06-27
> 17:15:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user
> 'mysql' db_1       | 2021-06-27 17:15:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]:
> Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.5.11+maria~focal started.
> db_1       | 2021-06-27 17:15:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]:
> Initializing database files db_1       | 2021-06-27 17:15:18 0 [ERROR]
> InnoDB: Operating system error number 22 in a file operation. db_1
> | 2021-06-27 17:15:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 22 means 'Invalid
> argument' db_1       | 2021-06-27 17:15:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File
> ./ibdata1: 'aio write' returned OS error 222. Cannot continue
> operation db_1       | 210627 17:15:18 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
> db_1       | This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible
> that this binary db_1       | or one of the libraries it was linked
> against is corrupt, improperly built, db_1       | or misconfigured.
> This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

At the same time, I want to note that if I execute the same commands but without mounting the file system, then everything goes fine.

Tell me, please, what is my mistake, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked out by itself after uninstalling Docker Toolbox and installing Docker Desktop.